# mt7921au チップセットを搭載したUSBドングルは日本で入手可能ですか？

Tags: usb, wifi

802.11acを搭載したPCを802.11axにアップグレードするため、USBドングルを購入したいと思っているのですが、なかなか技適を取得していて**mt7921au**チップセットを搭載している商品が見つからないのですが、
mt7921auチップセットを搭載した日本で売られている商品があれば教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします.

Comment: なぜそのチップセットが必要なのかも説明があると回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: mt7921au チップセットを搭載したUSBドングル というのはどういうものなんでしょうか

Comment: 上から順に答えます.
1.つけてみました.
2.mediatek製の1201+574のUSBのWifiチップセットのことです.

Comment: チップセットで探すより、802.11ax 対応で探せばいくらでも候補が出てくるかと思います。

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。